# Redis connection refused error in the application logs

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

We saw "Connection refused to ip:263*" to redis instances from the application logs. To solve we changed the port number from 26** to 6379 and it worked fine.

Upon analysis we found one one of the slave redis servers have the port number 26380 opened using

```
netstat -tupln
```

command. but the other server is not. Upon reading found that 26380, 26379, 26381 are ports used by sentinel. We suspect this 2**** ports should be opened on all servers and sue to some reasons it is not.

Please tell us how to check the logs in sentinel

1. checking if sentinel is configured.
2. checking if it is running.
3. checking what could have caused this to stop suddenly.

[redis logs for port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHlZT.png)

**EDIT**
this is what I can see from the sentinel logs
2907:signal-handler (1653294181) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
2907:X 23 May 16:23:01.105 # User requested shutdown...
2907:X 23 May 16:23:01.105 * Removing the pid file.
2907:X 23 May 16:23:01.106 # Sentinel is now ready to exit, bye bye...
433:X 23 May 16:25:08.364 # Creating Server TCP listening socket ipaddress:26379: bind: Cannot assign requested address
anotheripaddress